# Trigger to update a record to null whenever there is an insert or update on a row in the table in Oracle DB

Tags: database, oracle, triggers

Need help in writting a Trigger to update a record to NULL whenever there is an insert or update on a row in the table in Oracle DB.

**CODE**

```
create or replace trigger updateRowToNull
AFTER
UPDATE OR INSERT
ON CUSTOMER for each row
BEGIN
update customer set customeraddr=NULL;
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trigger cannot modify the table to which it is attached with a separate transaction. A  "before" trigger can, however, manipulate column values within the transaction that causes it to be fired.

```
create or replace trigger update_row_to_null
before update or insert on customer
for each row
begin
   :new.customeraddr := null;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks @pmdba. Sorry, I did not understand your answer. Could you explain me about this trigger, what it is going to do? I am new to Triggers.

Comment: A trigger on TABLE_A cannot have a separate update or insert transaction on TABLE_A. You will get a "mutating table" error. By using a "before" trigger and the "new." pseudo columns you can modify the value of a column in the original transaction. This trigger sets CUSTOMERADDR to NULL for every row inserted or updated on the table.

Comment: There is a slight change in the requirement. whenever there is an update to non null value in customeraddr value in customer table then that should be updated with null. Can any one help me with that requirement?

Comment: Isn't that effectively saying that customeraddr should be reset to null for any situation? It sounds like your test is "IF NOT NULL THEN MAKE NULL, OTHERWISE LEAVE NULL." That is what the trigger as written above does. Is there any situation in your requirement in which customeraddr would be allowed to remain NOT NULL? Or are you saying that customeraddr might be allowed to be not null on an insert, but not an update?